# MIT OpenCourseware Single Variable Calculus, Question about Derivatives in Problem 1C) 6

Tags: derivatives, slope

In the homework for MIT Open Courseware Single Variable Calculus, one of the questions involves drawing the derivatives of functions. I have included the picture from the answer key of the functions and the "correct answer" for the derivatives of those functions in my first image (functions are directly above their derivatives). In the second image, I included my answer. I didn't make the derivatives continuous because it seemed like there was a sharp change in the steepness at some points, and I had straight lines where the answer key had lines pointing down or pointing up because the function looked like a straight line.

I am a little rusty with derivatives and I want to make sure that my solution is fine before I just move past it.
[Functions and their Derivatives in the Answer Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul8RB.png)

[My answer for the derivatives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPFmT.jpg)